# Homey CLI or IDE

Tags: command-line-interface, homey

I installed the Homey CLI and also did the NMP (All on Windows 11 X64 machine).
So far so good.
But: I don't like working on windows cmd (going to cmd, going to node.js directory and do all the commands)
My question: is there an IDE available to do this (would like to start the IDE with possibility to do the Homey CLI stuff)
Can somebody help?

Comment: Any IDE that has an integrated terminal (which is most of them) can be used. That makes this a recommendation question, which is off-topic.